# How to reinterpret the bits of a float as an int

Tags: java, c++, casting

What is the Java equivalent of following C++ code?

```
 float f=12.5f;
 int& i = reinterpret_cast<int&>(f);
```

Comment: Did you check if the code runs successfully??

it should be `int& i = r_c<int&>(f)`

Comment: It is not really translatable into any language. It is interpreting the bits of the float as an int!!! What does that mean? Because the representation of floating point is undefined by the standard it only has meaning if you understand what floating point representation is used by your compiler/hardware here and know that this maps to the Java floating point representation.

Comment: In addition to what Martin York said, it is technically performing an *implementation-defined mapping* from float reference to int reference. Strictly speaking, there's no guarantee that the resulting int reference will alias the same object.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805058/is-there-cast-in-java-similar-to-reinterpret-cast-in-c

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
float f = 12.5f;
int i = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between what you posted and a int i = (int)f;?

Comment: @Montecristo : (int) f in Java is like static_cast<int>(f) in C++.

Comment: Ok... so I think I'll have to look for those two c++ methods to get the whole picture, thanks :)

Comment: @Montecristo : They are cast operators, not methods.

Comment: Note the C++ version uses int reference. Thus modifying the float will cause the int to change (in some undefined way). The Java version does not provide that functionality. Every change to 'f' must be followed by a call to floatToIntBits().