# typecast to single in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, casting

What does this call to `typecast` do in MATLAB?

```
y=typecast(x,'single');
```

what does it mean? When I run `typecast(3,'single')` it gives `0 2.1250`.

I don't understand what that is.

I am trying to convert this to Java, how can I do that?

From the MATLAB manual:

> single - Convert to single precision
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> B = single(A)
> ```
>
> Description
>
> `B = single(A)` converts the matrix A
>   to single precision, returning that
>   value in B. A can be any numeric
>   object (such as a double). If A is
>   already single precision, single has
>   no effect. Single-precision quantities
>   require less storage than
>   double-precision quantities, but have
>   less precision and a smaller range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typecast` reinterprets the bytes used to represent a value of one type as if those same bytes were representing a different type. For example, the constant `3` in MATLAB is an IEEE double-precision value, meaning it takes 8 bytes to store it. Those eight bytes in this case are

```
40 08 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

A value of type `single` in MATLAB is an IEEE single-precision value, meaning it takes only 4 bytes to store it. So the eight bytes of the double will map to two 4-byte singles, those being

```
40 08 00 00, and
00 00 00 00
```

It turns out that `40 08 00 00` is the single-precision representation of the value `2.125`, and as you might guess, `00 00 00 00` is the single-precision representation of `0`. I believe they come out in reverse order due to the endian-ness of the machine, and on a big-endian machine I think you'd get `2.125 0` instead.

In C++ this would be something like a reinterpret_cast. In Java, there doesn't appear to be as direct a mapping, but the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805058/is-there-cast-in-java-similar-to-reinterpret-cast-in-c) discuss some alternatives such as Serialization.

Comment: Your explanation was considerably better than mine :) Upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

From running `help typecast` it looks like it changes the datatype, but keeps the bit assignment the same, whereas `single( )` keeps the number the same, but changes the bit arrangement.

If I understand it, you could think of it like you have two boxes, each containing up to 8 balls. Lets say, box 1 is full, whilst box 2 contains 3 balls. We now `typecast` this into a system where a box holds 4 balls.

This system will need three boxes to hold our balls. So we have boxes 1 and 2 which are full. Box 3 contains 3 balls.

So you'd have [8,3] converted to [4,4,3].

Alternatively, if you converted the number into our new system in the same way as `single( )` works (e.g. for changing an `int8` to a `single`), you'd change the number of balls, not the container.