# Cast a hexadecimal string to a class object

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, deserialization, hexdump

I have a class like this:

```
public class Fields implements java.io.Serializable{
    public short ID;
    public int SSN;
    public long Number;
}
```

and I have a hexadecimal string with the value like this which each 2 characters is representative of a byte:

```
String str="1000180018000540AC80D6487653E5000100D40B7900D4C3FFF2FAFF8985";
```

Now I want to cast this string to the above class object in a schema like this:

```
//ID has short type so we need 2 bytes
ID=4096; //(decimal value of 1000)

//SSN has integer type so we need 4 bytes
SSN=402659328; //(decimal value of 18001800)

//Number has long type so we need 8 bytes
Number=378492038049986131; //(decimal value of 0540AC80D6487653)
```

This casting can be implemented in c++ with `<reinterpret_cast>` so easily but as the [Is there cast in Java similar to  in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805058/is-there-cast-in-java-similar-to-reinterpret-cast-in-c) question is said, I can implement that with serialization in java. I think serialization can be used when we serialize a class object to the byte arrays at first and second we can de-serialize the obtained bytes to the primitive class object, which is different from my propose a little, because I have a string (like bytes) which I want to de-serialize that. So how can I do that?

Comment: Serialization won't help you. It have very specific format which doesn't match yours. You have to parse your string manually.

Comment: @talex but C++ do that with `<reinterpret_cast>` easily. So there is no way like `<reinterpret_cast>` in java? Because speed is important to me and parsing manually with a high rate string data will be a bottleneck!

Comment: No `<reinterpret_cast>` would not have done it easily. It wont even work. "1000" is 4 ASCII bytes, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, C++ won't magically convert it to 2 bytes 0x10, 0x00.

Comment: @ahmadimortezaali if you want to use `<reinterpret_cast>` you have to use `c++` :) Java doesn't have anything like it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java Serialization has a very specific data format and it doesn't help you parse data that you get with a different pre-defined format. But [a `ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) can be useful in parsing this kind of data.

First you need to transform your string into an actual `byte[]` array. I'll use a simple solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java), feel free to pick another one that's more appropriate to your example:

```
byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // maybe!

short id = buffer.getShort();
int ssn = buffer.getInt();
long number = buffer.getLong();
```

Whether or not you need the `order()` call depends on what endianness your data is in. `ByteBuffer` defaults to `BIG_ENDIAN`, so you can just leave that call out if that's what you need.

Comment: This is nice use of NIO `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: Thank you very much! By changing `buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` to `buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);` the result which I want was reached perfectly!

Comment: @ahmadimortezaali: note that BIG_ENDIAN is the default, so in that case you can leave it out entirely as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `<reinterpret_cast>` would have worked. The internal byte representation of `"1000"` is 4 ASCII bytes. One for character `1` (`0x31`) followed by 3 characters `0` (`0x30`) , not `0x10, 0x00` hexadecimal. The result you will get in `id` with `<reinterpret_cast>` would be hex `0x31303030` not `0x1000`.

What you need to do is parse the different components of the string.

Something like this should do:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0,4), 16);
```

Comment: You probably meant `int id = ...`?

Comment: Yes, was going to do it in 2 lines but changed my mind, and forgot to change the type.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to `split` and `parse`

```
public Fields(String str) {
    ID = Short.parseShort(str.substring(0, 4), 16);
    SSN = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(4, 12), 16);
    Number = Long.parseLong(str.substring(12, 28), 16);
}
```