# Reinterpret char[] as object with fields

Tags: java, casting, primitive, reinterpret-cast, raw-data

I get as an argument `data` which is of type `char[]`.

Given the information `data` is organized as a `Packet` object. How do I convert `data` to be a `Packet`? `Packet` includes primitive fields, and array of object consisting of primitive fields too. Is there a way doing it in Java? I know in C, C++ it is easy...

```
    class Square{
        float x;
        float y;
        int size;
    }    

   class Packet{
        int first;
        int last;
        Square s[]; 
    }
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you'd expect here. You've got *textual* data, but you want to get floating point values out of it... what would that text look like for a `Square` with x=2.5, y=10.25, size=10 for example? If you've just performed some sort of plain "in memory dump" serialization, that's not great as a serialization format... and you'd almost certainly want `byte[]` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: Java has no `reinterpret_cast`. You can not _just_ convert arbitrary data to a different type. Improve your design instead. Also, please elaborate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there cast in Java similar to <reinterpret_cast> in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805058/is-there-cast-in-java-similar-to-reinterpret-cast-in-c)

Comment: In C, a `char` is 1 byte long, so when you say `char[]`, in Java that would be a **`byte[]`**, since Java's `char` is 2 bytes long. --- Since Java by default encodes in big-endian, and you're likely capturing raw data structures, which are likely little-endian, depending on the CPU used, you should use Java's **`ByteBuffer`** to read/write such structures.